# Aligning the bottoms of an img (float:left) and a nav (right:float)

Tags: html, css, alignment, css-float

CASE:
I want a 'main menu div'. All this needs is the logo on the left, and the horizontal nav bar on the right.

```css
.mainmenu {
 
}

#logo {
 float:left;
}

.menu {
    float:right;
 text-align:right;
}

.menu ul {
 list-style: none;
   padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

.menu ul li {
 display:inline;
 padding:1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainmenu clearFix"> 

  <div id="logo">
   <a href="home.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="menu">
   <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="wat.html">What</a></li>
      <li><a href="who.html">Who</a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
   </nav> 
  </div>
  
 </div>
```

Problem:
The nav bar is in the top right corner due to the float:right; but i want it do be bottom right, aligned with the bottom of the logo.

Question:
How would I do this in the easiest possible way?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you want your nav bar the the bottom right of the logo .. 
all you need to do is to clear the first float

```
.mainmenu {
}
#logo { float:left;
 }
.menu {
    float:right;
    text-align:right;
}
.menu ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.menu ul li {
    display:inline;
    padding:1em;
}
div.clear {
    clear:both; 
}
```

div class="mainmenu clearFix">

```
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="home.html"><img src="img/logo.png"></a>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>

    <div class="menu">
        <nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="wat.html">What</a></li>
              <li><a href="who.html">Who</a></li>
              <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>  
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is the exact answer I was looking for.

Comment: This is actually Wrong, The Links are Coming in a New Line

Answer (score 0):

I Prefer you to Use `Position:relative`  and `top`

Here is the Demo http://jsfiddle.net/8nnwytbL/318/

Comment: Thanks for thinking along but this solution will only work if the viewport is fixed. If you resize the browser etc. using a relative position with px values will make the nav bar go outside the containing div.